# Maximum length of a side of an acute triangle with a fixed area of 1.

Tags: geometry, inequality, maxima-minima, upper-lower-bounds, triangle-inequality

Is there a maximum length (or at least an upper bound) for a side of an ACUTE triangle with a fixed area? If there is , can it be found?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 1):

No. In cartesian coordinates consider the triangle joining $(-1/n,0), (1/n, 0)$ and $(0, n)$ for arbitrary value of $n$.

Comment: This serves better as a comment instead

Comment: May be but can I ask why?

Comment: Please read our guidelines for what constitutes a good question and answer @Tony Pizza

Comment: It's a perfectly fine question and answer as well. Just because it is short doesn't mean it's somehow not good. I keep seeing bad questions all the time and this isn't one.

Comment: Please read the guidelines. I am not here to argue @Tony Pizza

Comment: I've no problem with this good correct answer. I wish you had waited to post it until the OP edited the question to show some work of their own. The lack of such work is why the question has downvotes and votes to close.

Comment: @EthanBolker it did not look like an assignment question to me but looked like something that will pop up in my mind back in the days. If it's no effort assignment questions then I don't answer them most of the times unless it's a commonly occuring problem that can help others looking for similar information.

Comment: I agree that it's probably not an assignment question. I still think a quick answer was inappropriate.

Comment: Sure. I will think about it next time.